# change working directory from csh script

Tags: csh, argv, cd, backticks

I want to lookup some data of running processes, actually I'm searching for the scratch directory to a corresponding job-ID. I managed to do that manually by the following commands (assuming the job-ID is 12345):

```
find ~ -name '12345.out'
```

This finds the output file according to the job:

```
/home/username/somefolder/12345.out
```

The scratch directory is written to a file named .scrdir in that folder, so

```
cd | cat /home/username/somefolder/.scrdir
```

brings me where I want.

I now want to **combine that to a csh script or some alias** in my *.cshrc*.

---

My atempt so far:

```
#/bin/csh

set jobfile = `find ~ -name $argv[1].out`
set jobdir = `dirname $jobfile`
set scrdir = `cat $jobdir/.scrdir`
echo $scrdir
```

where the first argument value is a job-ID, 12345 e.g. This script prints the right scratch directory but I want it to change my actual working directory to the scratch directory after I've called the script. How can I change the working directory from within a csh script?

---

I would also be grateful for any advice to refine the question / -title.

Comment: It's not entirly clear to me what exactly you want, or what exactly your problem is. I think you already have a (non-working) attempt? You should probably add this to your question, as this would probably make it clearer where your problem(s) is/are.

Comment: Tried to change the directory with `pushd` and `popd` but when the script ends, the directory stack resets. (Obviously each subshell brings it's own directory stack.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are no shell functions in csh, the only solution I found is to call the script with `source`.

The script:

```
#/bin/csh

set jobfile = `find ~ -name $argv[1].out`
set jobdir = `dirname $jobfile`
set scrdir = `cat $jobdir/.scrdir`
cd $scrdir
```

To call the script:

```
source myscript.sh
```